# Верстка макета по 12-колонкам

Tags: html, css

Я бы хотел спросить.
1. Есть ли смысл использовать 16 колонок сетки при верстке, если в макете 12, но отступы за сеткой не сочетаются с макетом. Отступ перед логотипом у меня 144px, но сетка bootstrap'a делает 268px тем самым отступ слишком большой. Макет у меня шириной 1920 пикселей, а мой монитор 1366 пикселей. Первый скриншот  - это то, что я сверстал, а второй это макет. Как мне верстать? Первый раз такая проблема у меня. [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сетка bootstrap ограничивает отступы. Может мне сверстать сначала для своего экрана, а потом адаптировать под мобильный и 1920px?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было просто добавить медиа-запрос к контейнеру bootstrap и все станет как на макете)